# compile typescript in vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js

the code I am testing is the following:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

type test = { name: string; age: number }
let aa: test = {
  name: 'a',
  age: 12
}
aa.bbb = 'c'
console.log(aa)
</script>
```

> `<script lang="ts">`compile failed
> is correct

> `<script setup lang="ts">`compile successed
> is not correct

Comment: The question should contain clear problem statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "compile failed" - why? What is the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I guess your question is why, is ts setup not failing on building assets, correct? Since it is being assigned a property not existing in the test object types